# Adding Customized message in Inno Setup finish page

Tags: inno-setup

[image]I want to add few more lines in finishPage along with yes or no button, Can I get any help here please?
Currently I am getting default message along with that i will have to add few lines(instruction to user).

```
[Setup]
DisableFinishedPage=no
```

Comment: What *"yes or no button"* do you mean? Do you mean the "restart" question? It would help, if you post a screenshot showing what you have now and what you want instead.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  lets say, I am making an exe, once the install is finished, the program is going launch after that it will download the necessary assets.So I just want to give an instruction to the user at the Finished page that this is not an end still have to download  necessary assets for that i have give yes and No option

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have attached the screenCap above please check. I want add a line in this page along with Yes and No option

Comment: While adding Yes/No buttons is possible, a way easier would be to add a simple checkbox, like the one you have for "readme". Inno Sepup has facilities for that. Would a checkbox be ok?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes checkbox would be fine and thank you so much for your time! I got the solution

Comment: If you have a solution, please post it as an answer.